# Mkdir add number iteration

Tags: directory, mkdir

Lets say I have folder1 and I wanted to automatically make a folder2. Now lets say I ran this again and I wanted it to now make folder3, folder 4, and so on for each time I ran this. What would be the best way to make directory name + 1 of the largest number and then cd into it automatically?

Motivation:
I have a program I feed several types of input into that produces several output files. The program overrides output files if you run it twice or more. I'm designing a loop that will instead cp all the inputs into a folder, execute the program, write the output to that folder, cds back out, and repeats this in a new folder.

Comment: How many dirs do your expect at max? Or should it be unlimited?

Comment: Preferably there should be no limit epected. I'd like to specify a number of times for it to loop, 10-15 runs, since I'll be adjusting input parameters and analyzing data, culling weak input parameters for datasets. After 10-15 sets of 10-15 runs I'll probably do 100+ simulations

Comment: ideally id like for this to be able to detect preexisting folders and start from the previous value +1 since in the end all datasets will actually be useful (aka I will then probably run scripts analyzing all the datasets to track evolution parameters)

Comment: I'd rather use a timestamp instead of looping thru consecutive numbers and when you do `ls` later, then d10 appears before d2. You can retrieve the latest dir very easy..

Comment: i was  thinking about a timestamp too but the only issue then is that I dont have an easy way of tracking my revisions (folders 16-30 have x modification that 1-15 didnt) and if I figure out a way to script my culling procedure later on the timestamps wouldnt very obviously split different types of datasets

Answer (score 1):

Here's a bash function:

```
mknextdir () {
    stem=${1:-}
    lnum=$(echo "$stem"* | xargs -n1 | cut -c $(( ${#stem} + 1))- | sort -n | tail -n1)
    nn="${stem}$(( $lnum + 1))"
    mkdir $nn
    echo $nn
}
```

Call it as `mknextdir folder`, for your example case. It echoes the name of the directory it did create, so to move to it automatically you could do
`cd $(mknextdir folder)`, or store the output in a variable for scripting.

Comment: what does {1:-} mean

Comment: A reflex from a bunch of scripts which run under `set -u`; it means "provide the value of $1, or the empty string if $1 is unset". (And doesn't error out if nounset is on.) Practically speaking, if you provide no argument it'll make directories with bare numbers.